# How to create a custom Direct Stream(Receiver less) for Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How to create a custom Direct Stream(Receiver less) for Spark Streaming? From the examples that I can see from Apache Spark Documentation It looks like DirectStreams are only available for Kafka, ZeroMq etc but not say NSQ which is what I use. so I am wondering how to create a custom DirectStream since I want to go receiver less approach? For a receiver based approach it is pretty clear that we need to implement an interface called Receiver to create custom receivers likewise I would like to know how to create custom direct stream/receiver less ?